# Repeat an array over channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

For an array of shape(No of examples, row, height, channel). How can I simply replace channels with No of examples? I have searched for `np.repeat()` but I failed in applying it.

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([
                  [
                     [[0],[1]],
                     [[2],[3]],
                     [[4],[5]]
                  ],

                  [
                     [[0],[1]],
                     [[2],[3]],
                     [[4],[5]]
                  ],

                  [
                     [[0],[1]],
                     [[2],[3]],
                     [[4],[5]]
                  ],

                  [
                     [[0],[1]],
                     [[2],[3]],
                     [[4],[5]]
                  ]
                 ])
array.shape # (4, 3, 2, 1)
```

I want an array of shape (4, 3, 2, 4). Channels should be replaced with number of training examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
np.tile(array, (1, 1, 1, array.shape[0]))
```

or [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
np.repeat(array[:, :, :,], array.shape[0], axis=3)
```